# J How to get equation to multiply by itself?

Tags: j

How do I get this equation to multiply by itself?

```
*/-.%~.q:36
```

other than repeating the number 36 again. It's Euler's Totient Function by the way.

[image]

I'm lacking the last step of multiplying this by itself.

Yes, I know they already have the code for this function at jsoftware. But I'm trying to break down the codes and learn.

Sorry to ask such simple questions. It's really hard to find help for J on Google.

Comment: You'd want to accept some answers to your previous questions first.

Comment: I realize you may be implementing Euler's totient function for fun, but it is already built into J. Just say `5 p: 36` and the answer is 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer

```
y * (f y)
```

is

```
(* f) y
```

#### Longer answer

You have a case of

```
y f (g (y))
```

where `f` is the dyad `*` and `g` is the function that you already had: `*/-.%~.q:`. Now, `y f (g(y))` transforms simply to the "train" `(f g) y` (as you can see at the [manual](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/learning/03.htm)). Using [Cap](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d502.htm) `[:`<sup>*</sup> to parenthesize `g`:

```
g =: [: */ [: -. [: % [: ~. q:
```

we finally have:

```
phi =: * g
phi 36
12
```

or

```
(* [: */ [: -. [: % [: ~. q:) 36
12
```

<sub>* You can use [Atop](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d620.htm) and [At](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d622.htm) to construct function `g` but Cap is usually clearer for trains.</sub>

Comment: Can I ask why does this part "&." multiplies the numbers together. It's given by jsoftware "totient=: * -.@%@~.&.q:". Does it multiply only in this case?

Comment: @user: `&.` "combines and inverses". The inverse of `q:` is `*`. So, what does `~. &.  q:` mean? `q: y` are the factors of `y`, `~.` is the "nub" (unique items): `~. & q: y` are the unique factors of `y`, `&.` adds another step: the product of the unique factors of `y`. In other words: `~. &. q: y` is equivalent to `* (~. (q: y))`

Comment: Was it even written that the inverse of 'q:' is '*'. How did you find that out?

Comment: @user: See [this page](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d202n.htm) the lists on *"obverse"*. (`q:`'s inverse is actually `*/`). You should really consider opening new questions for this things.

Answer (score 2):

The most direct way to use the value again is to include the value again.

```
   */ 36, -. % ~. q: 36
12
```

A name can be used for the value.

```
   */ y, -. % ~. q: y=. 36
12
```

A verb can be defined. The name is local within it.

```
   etf=: verb : '*/ y, -. % ~. q: y'
   etf 36
12
```

The same verb can be phrased in tacit form. In this form the parameter is implied, not named. Here the key to using the parameter value twice is [the hook](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dictf.htm) created within parentheses.

```
   etfT=: */ @ ( , -. @ % @ ~. @ q: )
   etfT 36
12
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this what I came up with.

```
(* */@:-.@:%@~.@q:)36
```

Answer (score 0):

After I played around with this function trying to find out how it works and researching and the like (I only have a second year Calculus background), I looked back at an old tab for the primes function `p:` and found that J has built in Euler's totient function `5&p:` .